# Why is the arrow shorter than the distance between two nodes?

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a rather peculiar problem that I'm unable to fix:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\gal}[1]{\mathscr{G}_{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, column sep=small] 
  \phantom{K}\arrow[ddddd, mapsfrom, maps to, "\gal{K}" description, to path={ -- (\tikztostart.west) |-($(\tikztostart.west)!.5!(\tikztotarget.west)$)\tikztonodes -| (\tikztotarget.west)}]&  & \overline{F} & \phantom{K} \arrow[dddddd, mapsfrom, maps to, "\gal{F}" description, to path={ -- (\tikztostart.west) |-($(\tikztostart.west)!.5!(\tikztotarget.west)$)\tikztonodes -| (\tikztotarget.west)}]\\ 
  \phantom{K} \arrow[dddd, xshift=1.35em, mapsfrom, maps to, "\Gamma_K" description, to path={ -- (\tikztostart.west) |-($(\tikztostart.west)!.5!(\tikztotarget.west)$)\tikztonodes -| (\tikztotarget.west)}]& K_\infty \arrow[ur, dash, "\mathscr{H}_K"] & & \\
  & & F_\infty \ar[-]{ul} \ar[uu, dash, "\mathscr{H}_F"']& \phantom{K} \arrow[dddd, xshift=1.35em, mapsfrom, maps to, "\Gamma_F" description, to path={ -- (\tikztostart.west) |-($(\tikztostart.west)!.5!(\tikztotarget.west)$)\tikztonodes -| (\tikztotarget.west)}]\\
  & K_n \ar[-]{uu} & \\
  \phantom{K}& & F_n \ar[-]{uu} \ar[-]{ul} & \\
  \phantom{K} & K \ar[-]{uu} & \\
  & F \ar[-]{u} \ar[-]{uur} & &  \phantom{K}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

With this code (not necessarily minimal, I'm sorry!), the arrows labelled `\Gamma_K` and `\Gamma_F` are shorter than the distance between the nodes they are drawn? Am I missing something? The `Gamma_K` arrow (resp. `Gamma_F`) should stop at the same level as `K` (resp. `F`).

I'd appreciate any pointers about what I'm missing.

[image: output of the code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrow paths are overcomplicating things, and also causing an extension of the line past the bar in `maps from`.

I suggest a simplification of your code, using a `tikzcd` with 7 rows and only 2 columns. Then your outer "arrows" can be added at the end, shifted left or right by whatever amount you choose. For example, the `\Gamma_K` arrow is drawn from cell `2-1` to cell `6-1`, but shifted left by `1cm`. `start anchor=center` and `end anchor=center` places the arrows where you want them vertically.

Lastly, I added empty contents `{}` in cells `1-1` and `7-2` for placeholders instead of using `phantom`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\gal}[1]{\mathscr{G}_{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} 

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, column sep=small] 
{} & \overline{F}\arrow[dd, dash, "\mathscr{H}_F"] & \\
K_{\infty}\arrow[ur, dash, "\mathscr{H}_K"]\arrow[dd, dash]\arrow[dr, dash] \\
& F_{\infty}\arrow[dd, dash] \\
K_n\arrow[dr, dash]\arrow[dd, dash] \\
& F_n \\
K\arrow[d, dash] \\
F\arrow[uur, dash] & {}
\arrow[from=2-1, to=6-1, xshift=-1cm, mapsfrom, maps to, "\Gamma_K"description, start anchor=center, end anchor=center]
\arrow[from=1-1, to=6-1, xshift=-1.5cm, mapsfrom, maps to, "\gal{K}"description, start anchor=center, end anchor=center]
\arrow[from=1-2, to=7-2, xshift=1cm, mapsfrom, maps to, "\gal{F}"description, start anchor=center, end anchor=center]
\arrow[from=3-2, to=7-2, xshift=1.5cm, mapsfrom, maps to, "\Gamma_F"description, start anchor=center, end anchor=center]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's been a while since I had fiddled with Tikz-CD! Your code is much more natural! I appreciate your help.